# Ajax call waiting for audio media load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, audio

Hi I have a web page where I'm loading data through an Ajax call and in the page i have a `HTML5` `<audio>` element. When the user click on the a link the content is load with out any delay. But when a user is trying to play the `<audio>` element and then click on the content the Ajax call is waiting for all the audio media content to be loaded then processing the Ajax call.
I want to make a Ajax call even when other content is loading.

```
$.ajax({
            url: e.state.url,
            method: "POST",
            data: {history_nav:true},
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    var jdata = JSON.parse(data);
                    document.getElementById("app-content").innerHTML = jdata.html;
                    document.title = jdata.title;
                 }
              });
```

[image: Loading requests]

Comment: can you post code somewhere? or link? i believe what you are looking for is $when, see example http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2013/05/jquery-execute-multiple-ajax-request-simultaneously-in-parallel.html

Comment: hi @hardik link: https://www.musicmoron.com/

Comment: @hardik `$when` is for making parallel Ajax requests i believe. I'm not making parallel Ajax calls i'm making one Ajax call that is prevented by the loading media.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem wasn't with `Ajax` call it was the `PHP` locking the session and preventing the Ajax call. I just had to add `session_write_close();` to make the Ajax call work parallel to media loading.

Comment: I had the same problem. As PHP save & load session to file, It can be a bottle neck for performance. I used  session_start(['read_and_close'  => true])  to avoid session locking.